# Nested loop in helm charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have a nested ingress value in the helm charts values.yml as below

```
  hosts:
    - host:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
    - host: ppa
      paths:
        - path: /api/v1/ppob
          pathType: Prefix
        - path: /api/v1/pgob
          pathType: Prefix
```

with this, I'm trying to print all the routes through notes.txt with the code as

```
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
{{- $domainname := .Values.npdomain -}}
{{- $fullName := include "ppgp.fullname" . -}}
{{ println }}
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled }}
{{- range $host := .Values.ingress.hosts }}
  {{- range .paths }}
  http{{ if $.Values.ingress.tls }}s{{ end }}://{{ if .host }}{{ .host }}.{{ $domainname }}{{ else }}{{ $fullName }}.{{ $domainname }}{{ end }}{{ .paths.path }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

the output I'm expecting is if tls is enabled

```
https://ppgp.mydomainvar
https://ppa.mydomainvar/api.v1/ppob
https://ppa.mydomainvar/api.v1/pgob
```

The output I get is

```
https://ppgp.mydomainvar
https://ppgp.mydomainvar/api.v1/ppob
https://ppgp.mydomainvar/api.v1/pgob
```

I know something is incorrect, but I cannot figure it out as I have two .host blocks and I have two .path in the second .host block.

Appreciate it if someone could help with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you check `.host` you are in the innermost `range` loop.  In that context, `.` is one of the items from one of the `paths:` lists.

You already have a reference `$host` to the parent item in the `hosts:` list, and so the easiest fix is to change `.host` to `$host.host` the places where it appears.

Rather than immediately drilling down to the deepest level of the values structure and then trying to construct values from the parent context, you also might consider creating each of the parts of the URL at the level it appears.  Each item in `paths:` belongs to the same `hosts:` entry and will have the same host part of the URL, for example; this will make the line that emits the URL a little clearer.  That might look like:

```
{{- $domainname := .Values.npdomain -}}
{{- $fullName := include "ppgp.fullname" . -}}
{{- with .Values.ingress }}
  {{- if .enabled }}
    {{- $scheme := empty .tls | ternary "https" "http" }}
    {{- range .hosts }}
      {{- $host := printf "%s.%s" (.host | default $fullName) $domainName }}
      {{- range .paths }}
        {{- printf "%s://%s/%s" $scheme $host .path }}
{{ end }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: It worked with a small change to `{{- $scheme := .tls | ternary "https" "http" }}`  as I got the error  `NOTES.txt" at <"http">: wrong type for value; expected bool; got []interface {}`.
So, I changed it like this - `{{- $scheme := empty .tls | ternary "http" "https" }}` and it worked.  Thanks